# Automatic calls and database rollbacks

Tags: java, database, transactions

I've some code that reads from a table the list of mails to be sent and send them.

The operations in order are:

1. set the flag as sent in the table
2. make an automatic call
3. commit

The reason for having the update before the automatic call is that if something fail I can rollback and not make the automatic call. But if it was the other way around, I would end up in the possible scenario where I make a call without being able to update the record (if something goes wrong with the db).

```java
public class MyDao {

    public void doSomethingOnDb() {
        try {
            // operation 1 : execute an update (setting the letter as sent)
            // operation 2 : make automatic call    
            // operation 3 : commit
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // Rollback
        }
    }   
}
```

What I don't like here is that I'm placing a functionality to make automatic calls inside a dao and this is not what a dao is expected to do. But if I separate the logic I can't be really sure that the flag in the table is truthful. We can make a call and be unable to update the flag into the db:

```java
public class MyDao {

    public void doSomethingOnDb() {
        try {
            // operation 1 : execute an update (setting the letter as sent)
            // operation 2 : commit
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // Rollback
        }

    }   
}

public void someOtherMethodSomewhere() {
    try { 
        new MyDao().doSomethingOnDb();
        // operation 3 : make the automatic call
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

So, how would you do this? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical multiple resource transaction (distributed transaction). I could recommend you reading about XA-transactions and for instance [Two Phase Commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

Maybe you are trying to solve another problem? If I understand it correctly, then maybe you just need to change your code? E.g. you could return success from the dao:

```
if(doSomethingOnDb()) 
{
   //make the automatic call
}
```

i.e. the dao call returns true if changes done successfully and committed.

You could also just throw an exception from the doSomethingOnDb if it fails, in this case

```
try { 
    new MyDao().doSomethingOnDb();
    // operation 3 : make the automatic call
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
```

skips `operation 3` and falls into the catch block.

Or just pass to the dao a function to execute:

```
public void doSomethingOnDb(Runnable precommit) {
    try {
        // operation 1 : execute an update (setting the letter as sent)
        precommit.run();    
        // operation 3 : commit
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // Rollback
    }
}   

...
myDao.doSomethingOnDb(new Runnable()
{
   void run()
   {
        // operation 3 : make the automatic call
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply separate the DAO operations into submethods? Something like:

```java
public class MyDao {
    public void executeAnUpdate() {...}
    public void commit() {...}
}

public class MyBusiness {
    public void run() {
        myDao.executeAnUpdate();
        // make the automatic call
        myDao.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, maybe creating even a method for the rollback then. But it's less loose coupled in that way